# Left-recursion in ANTLR

Tags: antlr, left-recursion

The `stm` and `stmList` gives me this error, it seems that ANTLR see it like a possible infinite recursion loop. How can I avoid it? **The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive [stmList]**

```
stmList: stm stmList | ;
stm: ifStm | whStm;

ifStm: ifPart elifPart* elsePart?;
ifPart: IF LB exp RB CLB stmList CRB;
elifPart: ELIF LB exp RB CLB stmList CRB;
elsePart: ELSE CLB stmList CRB;

whStm: WHILE LB exp RB CLB stmList CRB;

LB: '(';
RB: ')';
CLB: '{';
CRB: '}';
WHILE: 'While';
IF: 'If';
ELIF: 'Elif';
ELSE: 'Else';
```

Comment: The `stmList` rule is right-recursive.  There's no left recursion here.

Comment: but ANTLR displays that error

Comment: @DuyDuy that could be, but not with the rules you posted. You've trimmed down the grammar too much. If you decide to strip the code/grammar and post it on SO, always make sure the original error is still being produced. I recommend posting the entire grammar.

Comment: @BartKiers you're right. I haven't define production for forStm that has been trimmed down

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because of the empty alt in `stmList`, though I also wonder why this error comes up. It doesn't seem right. However, I recommend not to use empty alts anyway, unless you guard the other alt(s) with a predicate and "call" the containing rule unconditionally. This can easily lead to problems when you forget that. Instead remove the empty alt and make the call optional:

```
stmList: stm stmList;
elsePart: ELSE CLB stmList? CRB;
```

Additionally, `stmList` looks pretty much like you would do such a definition in yacc, where no EBNF suffixes are possible. Instead just write:

`stmList: stm+;`

Comment: "I recommend not to use empty alts anyway": couldn't agree more